# How to show the type of a variable in Visual Studio Code in the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, edit, variable-types

I'm wondering which setting needs to be enabled in Visual Studio Code so that the variable type is viewed besides the variable declaration in the editor. On my Mac this works perfectly, on my Raspberry PI it does not work and I can't remember what I have done on my Mac to make this works. In my case I ask for Rust, but I guess this is a general setting in Visual Studio Code for all programming languages. The problem is that I have no clue what this editing / viewing feature is called and therefore it's kind of hard to search for this.

Below an example: the editor views the data type for square, which is in this sample [f64; 4].

[image: Type declaration for square]

Comment: Enable `Inlay Hints`.  Each language server provides its own support for this feature.